# How to find extrema points

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I took notes in my class on finding extrema points, but I don't understand what I wrote in my notebook.  I need to learn their solution methods before my exam tomorrow (this is not homework or similar).

1. Find maximum and minimum extrema points of $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ on $\overline{B_1(0)}$
2. Find all extrema of $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ subject to the constraint $g(x,y,z)=x-y-1$ and $h(x,y,z)=y^2-z^2-1$

Please help me to teach me possibly soon. Thank you so much:)

---

**Answer for first one:**

[image]

[image]

---

**Answer for second part** 
[image]

Comment: Please only dont say "apply Lagrange multiplier theorem and the like. I want to learn application. Thanks..

Comment: What do you mean by that comment?

Comment: You show us how far you get on both problems. Stop expecting us to write you an answer book over and over for you to memorize.

Comment: Somebody helps with only a hint. For example use  bla bla theorem, I want to state that only. I want full answer. Because this is very basic question, which is just to learn:) @PeterTamaroff

Comment: Mathemtics is memorized? Really? @TedShifrin

Comment: @Rsm1 You won't learn much if we give away the solution.

Comment: Apparently so, by you and others.

Comment: Well, I have nowhere I can learn. So, I asked here. No problem. @PeterTamaroff

Comment: Nowhere you can learn? How about studying your text, your notes, and asking your professor for help? Why wait until the night before the test to address the problem? You need to be working lots of homework problems every day, getting help from your classmates and professor.

Comment: No school No professor No classmater and so on ! . I am on summer holiday. And I failed the class previous semmester. Thus, I have one exam to pass tommorow.(like makeup exam) I am studying by myself though holiday. As I said, I dont understand my notes. So I asked here.  Okay? @TedShifrin

Comment: Let last line has a problem, which probably occurred because you used $f$ as the name of two different functions.

Comment: Okay, I noticed that. I need to write $g(x)$ instead of $f(x)$. Thanks. I write the solution for second part. Please check this this as well. Thank you:)@RGB

Comment: By the way, If you really want one to teach something, you should explain solution way in detail with all steps, and then the person should solve the question and you should check this. Like I did now. Okay?! Nobody learn on his own. Please dont forget! @PeterTamaroff

Comment: Also, I tell you the same things I wrote to Peter Tamaroff. @TedShifrin

Comment: @Rsm1 I disagree with "explain solution way in detail with all steps". You learn when **you** do things on **your own**. You cannot say you're flying by yourself if you're on an airplane you are not driving.

Comment: Wow you do have a very nice handwriting and just for some positive encouragement, it looks like you have potential for great understanding and clarity of mind as well as clear communication which are very useful in math of course. But you have to learn and make an effort yourself. Math is not a spectator's sport. Oh how I wish I could get my students to write like that.

Comment: @Rsm1 This isn't a site where we teach people. It's a site where we answer questions. "Please teach me this concept" questions are off topic for a question and answer site. Localize your problem to a single question, and ask it. If you have more questions, ask those as separate questions.

Comment: Thank you. You are so kind. @FixedPoint

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

1. To find extrema on a closed domain, you must check the critical
   points within the domain, and the points on the boundary.  The
   critical points of a function $f(x,y)$ occur where both partial
   derivatives are $0$.  For the function you've listed, there will be
   only one such, and it will lie in $\overline{B_1(0)}$.

   As for the boundary, notice it is given by the equation $x^2+y^2=1$, so that your function becomes $f(x)=2x^2-1$, with $x$ allowed to range from $-1$ to $1$.  Now try to maximize this function.
2. If you don't want to use Lagrange multipliers, you don't have to. 
   Assuming your constraints are supposed to equal $0$, we have the two
   equations $z^2=y^2-1$ and $y=x-1$.  This reduces our function to one
   variable:

   $$x^2+y^2+z^2=x^2+2y^2-1=3x^2-4x+1=f(x)$$

   Notice however that we cannot have $y\in(-1,1)$ else $z$ is
   imaginary.  This means that we can only take values of $x$ that lie
   outside of $(0,2)$ when searching for extrema of $f(x)$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I wait for such a explanatory answer. Some people really dont understand this. You are wonderful. Thank you:) by the way, ıf I write an answer with your the help of explanation, can you check this? I want to really learn properly.

Comment: @Rsm1 For what you want, it would be perfect you writing an answer here to your own question. You will get feedback right away.

Comment: Yes, I want feedback:) thank you thank you @RGB

Comment: @RGB I added the solution for first one. The solution of Second one is coming.. Thank you so much:) by the way, I am sorry for hand-writing, I cannot write fast with MathJax

Comment: Well, I have two question. Why range from $-1 $ to $1$ ? And If this is open set, then I dont check boundary points. Right? @RGB

Comment: Always the boundary is important, even if open. You need to study how the function behaves when you approach the boundary because the extrema may not exist. Existence should be ensured when you are attacking an optimization problem. The range is that because thats how that parameterization of the circle works.

Comment: @RGB I dont understand second one. I did something. But I am stuck with a point. Will I sent what I did about second question? Please show me this more clear..

Comment: By the way I want to solve secon question by using Lagrange theorem. @RGB

Comment: I added the photo. But I dont understand what I need to do after here. @RGB

Comment: @RGB Can you continue from there? Please :)